# Jasper ETL Parallel Execution after Mylsql Input

Tags: parallel-processing, etl

I use the Jasper ETL PRO Version and I load some data from the database with a tMysqlInput component. I connect this via main row to a tHttpRequest component to make a server call.

The server call takes some minutes so that the tMysqlInput is waiting. But I'd like to continue so that the tMysqlInput delivers the data already even if the tHttpRequest is not finished. The tHttpRequest should make the server call again with the new data. So that the server can handle the requests parallel.

Does anyone have a clue how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. After MysqlInput I use an FlowToIterate. On the Iterate link I can enable "parallel execution". I use 10 in this exammple.

[image: Parallel execution of HttpRequest]